# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/render3': ViewChildren QueryList

Tags: angular, angular5, viewchildren

(Angular CLI: 1.7.4)

I am using ViewChildren in a component. It is working fine if I define it as

```
@ViewChildren(TestComponent) testComponents;
```

However, when I specify the type of testComponents as QueryList:

```
@ViewChildren(TestComponent) testComponents: QueryList<TestComponent>;
```

it gives error:

`ERROR in ./src/app/components/search-component/search.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/render3' in 'D:\Test Applications\test-application\src\app\components\search-component'`

Answer (score 0):

Delete node-module folder and run 'npm install' command from the root directory.This installs all dependencies listed in package.json file.If you want to install specific package,execute'npm i your package name.
Let me know if it dosen't work?

Comment: Tried that. The node_modules folder already contains @angular/core/src/render3.